# Bootstrapping Sharpe Ratios

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, sharpe-ratio, bootstrapping

A similar question to this was asked here:

[How do i test the significance of Sharpe ratio of a strategy using bootstrap](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10830/how-do-i-test-the-significance-of-sharpe-ratio-of-a-strategy-using-bootstrap)

I have bootstrapped the original time series (using block bootstrapping) and now have calculated the Sharpe Ratio for those bootstrapped series, giving me a bootstrap estimate of the Sharpe ratio.

Only one out of 100 of the Sharpe Ratio's was less than zero, so can I say that the Sharpe Ratio is positive with 99% probability?

Also is there any rule of thumb as to how many booststrap resamples to use?
Is 100 sufficient?

Or is there something I have missed?

Baz

Comment: Any reason why you need to bootstrap? The Sharpe Ratio is only mildly affected by autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap is a very interesting method to obtain the **variance** of any estimator. 
This means you can rely on it to obtain de *variance* of your Sharpe ratio (SR), but what you try to do is to deduce something (the probability to be positive) from the *distribution* of it.

From a methodological viewpoint, if you boostrap your SR a "*standard*" way (i.e. randomizing samples of your underlying data), you create virtual samples of data that have no sense: what means having a conclusion mixing SR of yesterday with SR of 2 years ago without taking into account the ones in between? You try to bootstrap a time series, it is far more subtle, some techniques have been set up to do it. More or less, you have to apply a sliding kernel to them (of course you can do more subtle things to have the best possible statistical properties of you bootstrapped statistic), i.e. *preserve causality*.

The paper [Lectures on some aspects of the bootstrap](http://www.citeulike.org/user/lehalle/article/1343488) gives most needed details.

Moreover, a detail: if you focus on a statistic of your Sharpe ratio, no need to work on the Sharpe ratio itself, the sign of your its numerator is enough.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting and subtle question. You're testing a trading strategy, right? Presumably, it needs some time-series properties. If you do an independent bootstrap you'd mess those up.

At the same time, independent is good for looking at certain aspects (e.g., skewness over multiple horizons from a momentum strategy). Other than that, you'll probably need to consider a block bootstrap or other dependent bootstrap.

In its simplest form CBB (Circular Block Bootstrap)

- takes the data, lines up on a circle (to avoid endpoint problems), and
- For your blocksize N, you pick random starting points in the original dataset (on a circle)
- Fill in your bootstrap with the next N data points until your bootstrapped sample is the same size as the original.

Then run your strategy and calculate a Sharpe Ratio. From this, you can get a distribution of Sharpe ratios

The challenge is picking the right blocksize. Usually, this is done with reference to the autocorrelation function of the original timeseries.

For non-bootstrap statistics on Sharpe Ratios, Andy Lo has a paper called *The Statistics of Sharpe Ratios*, worth looking at. For IID, they are t-distributions. For non-IID, a HAC variance estimator is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the approach proposed in this paper (specifically Remark 3.2):
Ledoit, O., & Wolf, M. (2008). Robust performance hypothesis testing with the Sharpe ratio. Journal of Empirical Finance, 15(5), 850-859.

Comment: Well done majeed. Very good article.